# Windows power shell script to rename all files in each directory to parent's name

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I'm working on learning Windows PS - but *until than* I need some help writing a quick command:

I have a directory of directories, each directory has a unique name.

I need to rename all files within each of these directories to their parents name! As follows:

**Current Structure:**

```
/pdfdirectory/pdf_title_directory/filename.pdf
/pdfdirectory/pdf_title_directory123/filename.pdf
```

**After shell script:**

```
/pdfdirectory/pdf_title_directory/pdf_title_directory.pdf
/pdfdirectory/pdf_title_directory123/pdf_title_directory123.pdf
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With good faith that you are learning Powershell and will try out stuff:

```
gci .\test -recurse | ?{ -not $_.PsIsContainer } | 
%{rename-item -path $_.fullname -newname ($_.Directory.Name + $_.Extension)}
```

Of course, the above will fail it there is more than one file in the directory.

To understand the above learn basic Powershell commands like `gci` ( alias for Get-ChildItem) and Powershell pipeline concepts.

Comment: thanks! this gets me going -- lots and lots to learn and power-shell is on the list but I really wanted to run this - I do have multiple files -! But I think I can modify this to get it going...

Comment: @jordan.baucke - What do you mean multiple files? How can many files in the same directory have the same name since you are renaming it to the name of the directory?

Comment: it just has some other files, the `.PDF` files are the only files I need to rename - the others are not important.

Comment: solution worked just fine, considering the other files don't matter it renamed all the files in the sub-directories!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you can pipe the output from Get-ChildItem directly into Rename-Item, you don't need a foreach.  Also, and this is the clever part, the -NewName parameter value can be a script block that yields the new name.  This script block can use $_ to refer to the file object that is currently being processed.

So you could do something like this:

```
dir -Recurse -Include filename.pdf | ren -NewName { "$($_.Directory.Name).pdf" }
```

(I think it was Keith Hill that made me aware of this trick.)

Comment: @Thanks! I am reading: _Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches_ by _Don Jones_